# "Incorrect function" error when open a file at team foundation server

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2018

Code is on TFS 2018 and using source control Git, when cloning code repository from Visual studio 19 and VS 18 got an error, see below
when I go to TFS, and try to open some files do not open and show "Incorrect function" error, please see attached image and download option is not enable. Some members of my team, they had previously clone repo, they have code but they are facing issue when any corrupt file is present in the commit, so the commit can not be pushed. I tried the download as zip option to download the whole code, when I download, corrupt files are not downloaded and rest of the files are downloaded and some of the files of the specific folders are not downloaded because that folder contain corrupt file too, may be the corrupt file come first so it skip rest of the files of that folder. There are thousands of files in my source code and hundred of files are corrupted, even it is difficult to track which files are corrupted.

Anyone can tell me how to recover corrupt files on TFS so my issue would be resolved, thanks in advance.

Output window result:

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\teamfoundation\team explorer\Git\cmd\git.exe Cloning into 'E:\Repos1\Codebase'... POST git-upload-pack (gzip 63764 to 31908 bytes)

Remote: Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) Team Foundation Server

Remote: Found 121452 objects to send. (1968 ms)

Remote: Incorrect function. Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error. early EOF index-pack failed

[image: file not open]

Comment: Did this issue happen on a particular repository? Are you able to create a new repo and push commits to it? Did you do any update to the server?

Comment: Any update to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned other team member can not push commits, I assumed all your team members can not access the repo. Please try the following items:

1. Go to the TFS/Azure DevOps Server machine, and check whether you can access the repo on this machine.
2. Clean the cache folder on the server. The cache location can be found in your Administration Console.
3. Create a new repo and check whether you can push the commits. If you can push the commits and live with the new repo, you may delete the old repo.
4. Check whether you have database backup. If the issue caused by database corrupt, and you want it back, you would need to restore database.

Comment: thank you @Cece Dong, the network administrator team done some clean cache and some sort of troubleshooting and issue is resolved but they have not shared with me clearly.